# Return form array without rendering

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I have a simple form:

```
...
$builder
    ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
        'constraints' => [
            new Length(array('min' => 3)),
            new NotBlank(),
            ],
    ))
    ->add('username', TextType::class)
...
```

I want to return that form as JSON response instead of rendering it in `Twig` template, like this:

```
{
  fields: {
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      constraints: {
        'notBlank',
        lenght: {
          'min': 3
        }
      }
    },
    username: {
      type: 'text'
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible to return that kind of `array` without using third party bundles like `FOSRestBundle`?

Answer (score 0):

After two hours of search I found nothing interested, but based on one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32883190/3675759) I wrote this:

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

foreach ($form->all() as $field) {

    $name = $field->getName();
    $options = $field->getConfig()->getOptions();

    $fields[$name]['type'] = $field->getConfig()->getType()->getBlockPrefix();
    $fields[$name]['disabled'] = $options['disabled'];

    foreach ($options['constraints'] as $constraint) {

        $rules = [];
        // Get lowercase constraint name from class.
        $class = strtolower((new \ReflectionClass($constraint))->getShortName());
        switch ($class) {
            case 'length':
                $rules['min'] = $constraint->min;
                $rules['max'] = $constraint->max;
                break;
            // More constraints here.
        }

        $fields[$name]['constraints'][$class] = empty($rules) ? true : $rules;
    }
}

return new JsonResponse(['fields' => $fields]);
```

that gives me the following result, which I'm happy with:

```
"fields": {
        "email": {
            "type": "email",
            "disabled": false,
            "constraints": {
                "length": {
                    "min": 3,
                    "max": null
                },
                "notblank": true
            }
        },
        "username": {
            "type": "text",
            "disabled": false
        },
        "plainPassword": {
            "type": "repeated",
            "disabled": false,
            "constraints": {
...
```

Comment: Did you try the built-in symfony serializer?

Comment: Its not build in i think, but can you post an example how to achieve what I need? I'll accept if the functionality is the same/ similar.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.
Been using the FOSRestBundle & JMSSerializer combo and thought that the [symfony serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html) could do the trick also. Playing with the normalizers config, all i could get was: `{"email":[],"username":[]}`